# How to include fontawesome icons in discourse posts?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, discourse

I’ve seen this in the past and would love to be able to include fontawesome icons on a regular basis. Can’t find it! For right now if someone could help me with a hack I’d be grateful. I want to embed the fa-comments, fa-search and fa-sandwich (or whatever it’s called) in a post explaining discourse features.

Down the road… perhaps there’d even be appetite for a plugin to support fa tags as emoji? Came across this interesting page:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fontawesome-markdown

Comment: https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails is probably the easiest way

Comment: Whether you need only three of them, would not it be easier to just copy-paste emojis   ≣ ?